# Force dynamically generated checkboxes to allow only one to be selected

Tags: android, checkbox

I am generating a series of checkboxes dynamically.

[image]

I can check any one of the checkbox from that:

[image]

How can you  uncheck the checked checkbox when clicking on another checkbox?

edited

here i am adding my RadioGroup implementation and i am getting IllegalStateException 
final LinearLayout firstRowTxtLayout = new LinearLayout(fContext);
        firstRowTxtLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

```
    rbGroup.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rbButton = new RadioButton(fContext);
    rbButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rbButton.setId(rbTagincreament);
    rbGroup.addView(rbButton);
```

then i am adding this radioGroup in to another main linear layout

```
firstRowTxtLayout.addView(rbGroup); here i am getting the exception
```

Comment: Use `RadioGroup` because it provides only one option to check!

Comment: actually my requirement is checkbox only and here i am creating everything programatically not using any xml it is cross platform thing.

Comment: your requirement is probably that it looks like a checkbox. nothing prevent radio buttons to look like checkboxes.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I used RadioGroup with custom RadioButton but i changed RadioButton to Checkbox. It will behave like a RadioButton only i.e only single selection.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
            rb[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.single_radio_chice);
            rg.addView(rb[i]); 

        }
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        p.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        linear.addView(rg,p);

    }
```

selector

single_radio_chice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/check_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/check_on" />
</selector>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi now i have used RadioGroup to implement it now m getting 03-11 23:12:24.939: W/System.err(475): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @Kris could you please post the code where you are getting this error?

Comment: yes.. here i am adding my RadioGroup to another Linear layout firstRowTxtLayout.addView(rbGroup);

Comment: in above line m getting the exception

Comment: @kris before firstRowTxtLayout.addView(rbGroup); write this  if(firstRowTxtLayout.getChildCount() > 0) 
    firstRowTxtLayout.removeAllViews();

Answer (score 2):

Get the reference of all checkbox in different variable.

```
satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
          if(isChecked) {
            checkBox.setChecked(false); //Here call this method on all checkbox except you want to check single checkbox.
        }
   }
}
```

But better approach is use `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton` because Radio buttons allow the user to select one option from a set.
Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html).

Comment: i am agree with RadioGroup and i have tried also.my code is bit  different like i am doing without any xml. with List<Views> getView i  am show all my views. and when i use RadioGroup with a Layout m gettin g java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your dynamically created `RadioButtons` into array. and when you check one of them go over all the others and `setChecked(false);`

As mentioned `RadioGroup` can be a solution too. but for some reason I found it hard to use if you want to put other objects like `ImageViews` or `TextView` between the `RadioButtons`.